# Forever.js: Using one instance for multiple users

Tags: node.js, config, forever

I've got Forever.js running, but what I'm trying now is to let more than one user use the same Forever.js instance.

If I start a file with Forever.js right now, I cannot see/stop/restart it with another user. If I do `Forever.js list` there, it shows that nothing is running.

I've tried some things with setting the config values differently, for example:
`forever set root '/tools/node/forever'` and get back `Forever config saved: /tools/node/forever/config.json`, but when I run `forever config` then, the file is reset back to what is was.

Would I be able to set the config from both users to the same folder, and would it then share the same Forever.js instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forever stores the current processesin the users home directory, so you can't share the same process with several users. The easiest way is to set up a service-user and switch to that user whenever you need to stop/restart your process (which shouldn't be too often).

Alternatively, you can set up an init.d script as described in this guide: [Running a Node.js Server as a Service Using Forever](http://www.exratione.com/2011/07/running-a-nodejs-server-as-a-service-using-forever/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried to follow that tutorial, but whenever I run that service, I get to see this: 'bash: forever: command not found' on line 63. Am I doing anything wrong there?
If I run forever in the command line there are no errors...

Comment: You should use the whole path (`/usr/local/bin/forever`, try `which forever` to get the path on your system.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked.
I've now fixed the service script and got what I want! Next to this thing I didn't know there were a couple of bugs in the tutorial :/ Not very conventional.

Comment: If forever is installed using `npm`, it has to be installed with the `-g` option:  `npm install forever -g`

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to kill the forever process after `ps -aux | grep forever`